# Creating a tagged union using F# Struct with Explicit LayoutKind

Tags: f#

I'm trying to create an F# equivalent of tagged union. I need it in hot path of the application code, where discriminated unions could cause too much of heap allocations.

Here's the example:

```
[<Struct; StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)>]
type Result =
    [<DefaultValue; FieldOffset 0>]
    val mutable IsAsync : bool
    [<DefaultValue; FieldOffset 1>] 
    val mutable Async : Async<obj>
    [<DefaultValue; FieldOffset 1>] 
    val mutable Sync : obj
```

However, problems start when I want to provide some kind of creation methods for it.

Example 1

```
static member Async(a:Async<obj>) = Result(IsAsync = true; Async=a)
static member Sync(s:obj) = Result(IsAsync = false; Sync=s)
```

Throws *The member or object constructor 'Result' takes 0 argument(s) but is here given 1. The required signature is 'Result()'* compilation error.

Example 2

```
new(a:Async<obj>) = { IsAsync = true; Async = a; }
new(s:obj) = { IsAsync = false; Sync=s }
```

Throws *Extraneous fields have been given values* compilation error.

Comment: So why not use a DU which is a tagged union?

Comment: This struct will be used heavily in hot path of the application logic. I need a good performance with a low GC pressure. F# Discriminated unions are implemented using class inheritance and cause heap allocations, which is no go for this case.

Comment: Maybe you can write the bad object as null and then overwrite it?

Comment: What version of F# are you using?

Comment: This compiles just fine: https://dotnetfiddle.net/85YT2J . Although it doesn't run, complaining about reference fields at the same alignment, which it totally should: you can't have an explicitly laid out structure with safe references overlapping each other. The GC won't know what to do with it. Consider having them as separate fields.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin - it is unverifiable, but allowed, for references to completely overlap each other.  It is not allowed for reference fields to partially overlap each other, or to overlap in any way with value fields.  See section 10.7 of Partition II of the [ECMA CLI](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-335.pdf) spec.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have three problems:

1. You need to separate constructor arguments with commas (`,`), not semicolons (`;`).
2. Object references must be aligned on pointer-sized boundaries.  Therefore, on x64 the offset for the object references must be 8.
3. Static and instance member names shouldn't overlap.

This works for me:

```
[<Struct; StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)>]
type Result =
    [<DefaultValue; FieldOffset 0>]
    val mutable IsAsync : bool
    [<DefaultValue(false); FieldOffset 8>] 
    val mutable Async : Async<obj>
    [<DefaultValue; FieldOffset 8>] 
    val mutable Sync : obj

    static member MakeAsync(a:Async<obj>) = Result(IsAsync = true, Async=a)
    static member MakeSync(s:obj) = Result(IsAsync = false, Sync=s)
```